# mail function does not echo value in email

Tags: php, email

this php code is correct.this code having no errors but when user submits form ,in received email only shows file attachment in email.it does not show all input fields values. what is required to do ???

```
    <?php
if(isset($_FILES) && (bool) $_FILES) {
    $AllowedExtensions = ["pdf","doc","docx","gif","jpeg","jpg","png","rtf","txt"];
    $files = [];
    $server_file = [];
    foreach($_FILES as $name => $file) {
        $file_name = $file["name"];
        $file_temp = $file["tmp_name"];
        foreach($file_name as $key) {
            $path_parts = pathinfo($key);
            $extension = strtolower($path_parts["extension"]);
            if(!in_array($extension, $AllowedExtensions)) { die("Extension not allowed"); }
            $server_file[] = "uploads/{$path_parts["basename"]}";
        }
        for($i = 0; $i<count($file_temp); $i++) { move_uploaded_file($file_temp[$i], $server_file[$i]); }
    }
    $from = "example@gmail.com";
    $headers = "From: $from";
    $semi_rand = md5(time());
    $mime_boundary = "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$semi_rand}x";
    $headers .= "\nMIME-Version: 1.0\n" . "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\n" . " boundary=\"{$mime_boundary}\"";
    $message = "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\n\n" . "--{$mime_boundary}\n" . "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\n" . "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n"; 
    $message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n";
    $FfilenameCount = 0;
    for($i = 0; $i<count($server_file); $i++) {
        $afile = fopen($server_file[$i],"rb");
        $data = fread($afile,filesize($server_file[$i]));
        fclose($afile);
        $data = chunk_split(base64_encode($data));
        $name = $file_name[$i];
        $message .= "Content-Type: {\"application/octet-stream\"};\n" . " name=\"$name\"\n" .
            "Content-Disposition: attachment;\n" . " filename=\"$name\"\n" .
            "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n" . $data . "\n\n";
        $message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n";
    }
}

/** Your submit block **/
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $name = htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['name']);
    $email = htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['email']);
    $mobile = htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['mobile']);
    $company = htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['company']);
    $qty = htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['qty']);
    $msg = htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['msg']);

    $subject = "Order Information";
    $message .= "Name: " . $name . "\n";
    $message .= "Email: " . $email . "\n";
    $message .= "ContactNo: " . $mobile . "\n";
    $message .= "Company: " . $company . "\n";
    $message .= "Quantity: " . $qty . "\n";
    $message .= "Message: " . $msg . "\n";
    if(mail($from, $subject, $message, $headers)) {   
        echo 'thank you';   
    }
    else { 
        echo 'error';
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: after adding error_reporting(E_ALL);ini_set('display_errors',1);$from = '';$to = '';$message = '' $headers ='';PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '$headers' (T_VARIABLE)  on line 2 at this code....

Comment: keep error reporting as it is ???

Comment: can you give that code with . added ???

Comment: can you update with full code ?? i have added as it is but gives  error unexpected '$headers' (T_VARIABLE) on line 2

Comment: i have added  $headers .= "From: $from"; on line 18 and $message .= "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\n\n" . "--{$mime_boundary}\n" . "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\n" . "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n";  on line 22 there are no error but not getting complete email only getting attachment...

Comment: i have again executed & got this errors PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: message in mail.php on line 12
 PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: from in mail.php on line 34
 PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: headers in mail.php on line 35

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to convert part where you send post data to multipart also. Otherwise your mail client will probably ignore it (I think you may find it at the bottom of mail in "view mail source" mode).

It should be something like (only $_POST part):

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $name = htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['name']);
    $email = htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['email']);
    $mobile = htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['mobile']);
    $company = htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['company']);
    $qty = htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['qty']);
    $msg = htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['msg']);
    $to="amar.ghodke30@gmail.com";
    $subject = "Order Information";
    $message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n"; //$mime_boundary should be the same as for attachments.
    $message .= "Content-type: text/plain;charset=utf-8\n\n";
    $message .= "Name: " . $name . "\n";
    $message .= "Email: " . $email . "\n";
    $message .= "ContactNo: " . $mobile . "\n";
    $message .= "Company: " . $company . "\n";
    $message .= "Quantity: " . $qty . "\n";
    $message .= "Message: " . $msg . "\n";
    $message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n\n";
    if(mail($from, $subject, $message, $headers)) {   
        echo 'thank you';   
    }
    else { 
        echo 'error';
    }
}
```

Comment: You may give it a try, but I'm not sure if it will not have errors.

Comment: i replaced with above code and it gives the email now as : Content-type: text/plain;charset=utf-8

Name: example
Email: example@gmail.com
ContactNo: 1234567890
Company: abc
Quantity: 1
Message: ty not attachment...

Comment: The part of code I provided is only $_POST processing part. I did not include what is above `/** Your submit block **/` in question. So you need to leave it as is.

Comment: _it Worked For me_ **Thanks**